# Performance of parsing math functions

Tags: python, performance, parsing, python-3.x, functional-programming

I wrote the following code as part of a larger application. This code takes a string that defines a mathematical function on such as `r,y x[0], x[1] etc.` or any other variable that additionally can be subscripted (indicated by the `x[0]` notation) and returns valid python function that accepts the the arguments and computes the final value.

For instance, the string "x+y" gets converted to `lambda x,y: x+y`.

Since the larger application will be calling the returned function repeatedly I would like to optimise the calling of the returned function. (The overhead for converting the function isn't much of any issue). That is when I noticed a disparity: the equivalent function hard coded into python is over 45 times faster!

Is there a way to reduce the time it takes to call the returned function?

Aside from the performance reason for posting this I would appreciate some constructive criticism regarding the quality and clarity of my code. I am aware that the current version doesn't indicate syntax errors in the entered expression, however I am working on the assumption that some exception will be thrown if that is the case. If this doesn't work in some cases I've missed please let me know.

```
import math

class Parser:
    """A recursive parser of mathematical expressions that
     supports variable and subscripted variables"""

    #Defines the binary operators that can be used in the expressions
    operators=[['+', lambda x, y: x+y],
                ['-', lambda x, y: x-y],
                ['*', lambda x, y: x*y],
                ['/', lambda x, y: x/y],
                ['^', lambda x, y: x**y]]
    #Defines the functions that can be used in the expressions
    functions={'sin':math.sin,
                'cos':math.cos,
                'tan':math.tan,
                'asin':math.asin,
                'acos':math.acos,
                'atan':math.atan,
                'sqrt':math.sqrt,
                'abs':math.fabs,
                'floor':math.floor,
                'ln': (lambda x: math.log(x,math.e))}
    #Defines the constants that can be used in the expresions
    constants={'pi': math.pi, 'e': math.e}


    def __init__(self,st):
        #Accepts the mathematical string in st

        st=st.strip()#removes whitespace 

        #This provides leading minuses with the implied argument to the minus operator
        if(st[0]=='-'):
            st='0'+st

        #look for any operators that can be tackled
        found_match=self.operator_handle(st)
        if(found_match == 1): return

        #look for additional brackets e.g. ((1+2))
        if(st[0]=='(' and st[-1]==')'):
            #If found replace this nodes content with that inside the ()
            inside_tree=self.__class__(st[1:-1])
            self.function=inside_tree.function
            self.leaves=inside_tree.leaves
            return

        #look for any functions that can be tackled
        found_match=self.function_handle(st)
        if(found_match == 1): return


        self.leaves=[] #make sure the self has "leaves" attribute

        #the expression a singular entity e.g. number or variable
        self.singles_handle(st)


    def operator_handle(self,st):
        "Searches for operators that can be handled"

        #Look for operators in standard order of operations order
        for op, func in self.operators:

            #this variable ensures we don't parse any operators inside parenthesis yet
            braket_level=0
            #the string is revesed to make equal levels of operations be processed left to right
            for char in reversed(range(len(st))):
                #change braket levels when needed
                if(st[char]==')'): braket_level+=1
                elif(st[char]=='('): braket_level-=1

                #operator found outside any brakets
                elif(st[char]==op and braket_level==0):
                    #save the associated function in self.function
                    self.function=func
                    self.leaves=[]
                    #leaves contain further levels of recursion on the arguments
                    self.leaves.append(self.__class__(st[:char]))
                    self.leaves.append(self.__class__(st[char-len(st)+1:]))

                    #indicate success to __init__ functions
                    return 1

    def function_handle(self,st):
        "Searches for functions that can be handled"
        #tests if the function name matches up with the string beginning
        for fu,func in self.functions.items():
            if(st[:len(fu)] == fu):
                self.function=func
                #still need functions with multiple arguments
                self.leaves=[self.__class__(st[len(fu)+1:-1])]
                #indicate success to __init__ functions
                return 1


    def singles_handle(self,st):
        "Handles static expressions"
        #looks if the string is meant to represent a constant
        if(st.lower() in self.constants):
            self.function=self.constants[st.lower()]
            return

        try:
            #If it is a number set function equal to it
            self.function=float(st)
        except ValueError:
            #Otherwise assume its a variable
            self.function=st


    def travel(self):
        "Returns a python function that reflect the tree of self"

        #if function type is a simple number return a function that returns it
        if(type(self.function)==type(1.0) or type(self.function)==type(1)):
            def actual_function(**kargs):
                return self.function

        elif(type(self.function)==type(' ')):

            #if the function contains [ and ] assume its a subscripted variable
            if('[' in self.function and ']' in self.function):
                def actual_function(**kargs):
                    #the variables index "picked" from the list in the user arguments
                    return kargs[self.function.split('[')[0]][int(self.function.split('[',1)[1][:-1])]

            else:
                #other wise return a function that returns its variable "picked" from the user arguments
                def actual_function(**kargs):
                    return kargs[self.function]

        else:
            #return a function that returns the value of this nodes function using the leaves as arguments
            def actual_function(**kargs):
                return self.function(* list(map(lambda x: x.travel()(**kargs), self.leaves)) )

        #return the function that we determined in the previous step
        return actual_function

if __name__ == '__main__':

    #simple example demoing all the features
    text_function="-2^x[0]*(sin(pi*y))+2*x[1]"
    python_function=Parser(text_function).travel()

    #showing it works
    print(python_function(x=[0,0],y=0.5))
    print(python_function(x=[1,2],y=1.5))
    print(python_function(x=[0,1],y=1.5))

    #create a regular python function for performance testing
    def non_parser_function(x,y):
        return -2**x[0]*(math.sin(math.pi*y))+2*x[1]

    import timeit

    a=timeit.Timer(lambda: python_function(x=[0,0],y=0.5))
    b=timeit.Timer(lambda: non_parser_function(x=[0,0],y=0.5) )

    print("timeit results")
    print("parser: ",a.timeit(1000))
    print("python: ",b.timeit(1000))
```

[Pasteall](http://www.pasteall.org/57137/python) for better formating

Answer (score 4):

While I'm still unsatisfied with the code I managed to take it from 45 times slower to 15 time slower then hard coding.

```
def travel(self):
    "Returns a python function that reflect the tree of self"

    #if function type is a simple number return a function that returns it
    if(type(self.function)==type(1.0) or type(self.function)==type(1)):
        def actual_function(**kargs):
            return self.function

    elif(type(self.function)==type(' ')):

        #if the function contains [ and ] assume its a subscripted variable
        if('[' in self.function and ']' in self.function):
            var_name=self.function.split('[')[0]
            var_index=int(self.function.split('[',1)[1][:-1])
            def actual_function(**kargs):
                #the variables index "picked" from the list in the user arguments
                return kargs[var_name][var_index]

        else:
            #other wise return a function that returns its variable "picked" from the user arguments
            def actual_function(**kargs):
                return kargs[self.function]

    else:
        #return a function that returns the value of this nodes function using the leaves as arguments
        function_list=list(map(lambda x: x.travel(), self.leaves))
        def actual_function(**kargs):
            return self.function(* [x(**kargs) for x in function_list] )

        # def actual_function(**kargs):
        #     return self.function(* list(map(lambda x: x.travel()(**kargs), self.leaves)) )

    #return the function that we determined in the previous step
    return actual_function
```

The key lies in redefining travel such that as much as possible is calculated outside actual_function.